# How to convert device with Monopole antenna to Directional/Dipole antenna?

Tags: antenna-system, dipole, transmitter, yagi, microphone

I'm trying to increase the transmission range of a stationary wireless microphone toward its receiver by connecting a yagi antenna. Aside from the antenna sticking out of the top, I don't know where the other pole is or how it's grounded. Is it possible to find a spot in the circuit of one such device that could connect to the second element of a yagi antenna, or at least make it possible to connect it to an rf amplifier?

Comment: is the receiver also stationary? Neither mathematically nor technically it makes a difference for signal strength on which end you attach the high-gain antenna, but it's more common for microphone receivers to have ports for that, and, bonus, if you have a high gain antenna on receive side, it becomes numb towards interferers not in the main direction of the antenna

Comment: The receiver is stationary but accessing it isn't terribly easy. If all else fails, I'll climb into the attic and deal with the receiver, but if there is a way to amplify the transmission instead, that would certainly be preferred.